# Pull from a list in a dict using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have this Document in mongo engine:

```
class Mydoc(db.Document):
    x = db.DictField()
    item_number = IntField()
```

And I have this data into the Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e360cce725070909af4953"),
    "x" : {
        "mongo" : [
            {
                "list" : "lista"
            },
            {
                "list" : "listb"
            }
        ],
        "hello" : "world"
    },
    "item_number" : 1
}
```

Ok if I want to push to mongo list using mongoengine, i do this:

```
Mydoc.objects(item_number=1).update_one(push__x__mongo={"list" : "listc"})
```

That works pretty well, if a query the database again i get this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e360cce725070909af4953"),
    "x" : {
        "mongo" : [
            {
                "list" : "lista"
            },
            {
                "list" : "listb"
            },
            {
                "list" : "listc"
            }
        ],
        "hello" : "world"
    },
    "item_number" : 1
}
```

But When I try to pull from same list using pull in mongo engine:

```
Mydoc.objects(item_number=1).update_one(pull__x__mongo={'list': 'lista'})
```

I get this error:

> mongoengine.errors.OperationError: Update failed (Cannot apply $pull
>   to a non-array value)

comparising the sentences:

```
Mydoc.objects(item_number=1).update_one(push__x__mongo={"list" : "listc"}) # Works
Mydoc.objects(item_number=1).update_one(pull__x__mongo={"list" : "listc"}) # Error
```

How can I pull from this list?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that mongoengine doesn't know the structure of your `x` document. You declared it as `DictField`, so mongoengine thinks you are pulling from `DictField` not from `ListField`. Declare `x` as `ListField` and both queries should work just fine.

I suggest you should also create an issue for this:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues

As a workaround, you can use a raw query:

```
Mydoc.objects(item_number=1).update_one(__raw__={'$pull': {'x.mongo': {'list': 'listc'}}})
```

Comment: Thank you, __raw__ works pretty well, also is better to use mongodb syntax.